# Is there a way to store a pdf annotation on a click?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pdfkit

I'm building a Machine Learning app to read info of pdfs, to train my algorithm I need to get the pdf annotations location. Is there a way to set a gesture recognizer and add the annotation to an array upon click? I successfully added the annotations to a pdf upon a regex. But I need to add the annotation and its associated info (location in the document upon a click) can I add a gesture recognizer to an app? My app uses SwiftUI.

```
func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<PDFViewRepresentedView>) -> PDFViewRepresentedView.NSViewType {
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    let document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"[0-9.,]+(,|\.)\d\d"#, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let string = document?.string!
    let results = regex.matches(in: string!, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(0..<(string?.utf16.count)!))
    let page = document?.page(at: 0)!
    results.forEach { (result) in
        let startIndex = result.range.location
        let endIndex = result.range.location + result.range.length - 1
        let selection = document?.selection(from: page!, atCharacterIndex: startIndex, to: page!, atCharacterIndex: endIndex)
        print(selection!.bounds(for: page!))
        let pdfAnnotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: (selection?.bounds(for: page!))!, forType: .square, withProperties: nil)
        document?.page(at: 0)?.addAnnotation(pdfAnnotation)
    }
    pdfView.document = document
    return pdfView
}
```

and get the tap in

```
func annotationTapping(_ sender: NSClickGestureRecognizer){
    print("------- annotationTapping ------")
}
```

If some one has achieved this, by adding an observer or something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PDFView already has a tap gesture recognizer attached for annotations,  so no need to add another one.  When a tap occurs it will publish a `PDFViewAnnotationHit` notification. The annotation object can be found in the `userInfo`.

Set up an observer for the notification in `makeUIView` or wherever else makes sense.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .PDFViewAnnotationHit, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
      if let annotation = notification.userInfo?["PDFAnnotationHit"] as? PDFAnnotation {
        print(annotation.debugDescription)
      }
    }
```

or better, handle the notification in your SwiftUI View.

```
 @State private var selectedAnnotation: PDFAnnotation?
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Selected Annotation Bounds: \(selectedAnnotation?.bounds.debugDescription ?? "none")")
      SomeView()
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .PDFViewAnnotationHit)) { (notification) in
          if let annotation = notification.userInfo?["PDFAnnotationHit"] as? PDFAnnotation {
            self.selectedAnnotation = annotation
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great! Can you give me an example of this? Thanks

Comment: sure, expanded the answer a bit

Comment: Amazin!! I need to deep dive into publishers, one more question, why does it gets fired 14 times? Is because I added more than one annotation to that particular text? Neither way thanks a lot

Comment: Probably multiple objects all handling the notification. You have to be careful about retain cycles with notification closures. Try this other approach where the notification handling is done right in the SwiftUI View and you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: One last question, is therea way to add an id to annotation? This is to know which annotation was clicked, because all the added annotations are notified that one was clicked. I want to be notified of only one (the one that I clicked)

Comment: The notification will be posted every time any annotation is hit, can't change that. But the post includes a reference to which _specific_ PDFAnnotation object triggered it. In the code above, it will be the `annotation` variable. You can access all the PDFAnnotation properties through there (or ignore it or save it or pass it to another function, etc).